# Where to verify password using MVC?

Tags: java, swing

In Netbeans Im creating simple program using MVC that have two packages GUI and Core. In Swing GUI I have a method that verifies the user password. Is it acceptable approach to verify a user password directly in GUI instead of sending it to a core system perhaps to a coordinating class to check if the password matches and returning answer back to GUI?

Comment: UI is not the place to do such things.  That's what a service interoperating with a database should do.

Comment: Alot depends on how you system is setup. My personally opinion is, if you have a service which stores the password, it's the services responsibility to verify, why? Because as much as possible, you don't want to tell the rest of the word "how" that password is managed/stored. This raises a dozen more questions, but essentially, you don't want to transmit the password in the clear, you want to transmit over a secure channel (HTTPS) and maybe even have an agreed encryption protocol in place between the client and the service

Answer (score 1):

*You can validate password policy on client side if you have one (i.e.    min 3 letter 2 digit etc...)

*You can validate user input as a valid    String (or char[]) and again password    policy on frontend again (User can    manipulate client side but it    will save some time for most of inputs)

*You can validate actual password by comparing on backend (you prefer    hashing for that)